# Is it possible to add MXML elements to the main application using Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I'm an Actionscript & MXML newbie.

There's an HTML technique known as innerHTML that allows Javascript to add/delete/edit HTML elements. Can actionscript do something similar to MXML?

For example, my main application's mxml part is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Button x="29" y="347" label="Button"/>
</mx:Application>
```

But after running an actionscript code, I want the user to see the result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Button x="29" y="347" label="Button"/>
<mx:RichTextEditor x="183" y="24" title="Title">
</mx:RichTextEditor>    
</mx:Application>
```

Is this possible with Actionscript inside a MXML file?
ALso, if it IS possible, I would appreciate if you would teach me how :)
p.s: is this possible with Degrafa library elements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately imposable, if you wont to add components dynamically you should do it inside script tag by using ActionScript 3
Like this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.RichTextEditor;


        protected function addRichEditor():void{
        var rEditor:RichTextEditor=new RichTextEditor();
        rEditor.x=183;
        rEditor.y=24;
        rEditor.title="Title";
        addElement(rEditor);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```